# Chained middlware causes Express request to hang forever

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am following a middleware chaining example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34468395/2662227).

I have a route `app.put('/users/:id', isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {db.updateUser(req.params.id, req.body)}`. I am trying to write a middleware function that verifies that the ID provided in the URL matches the ID retrieved from the JWT included with the request.

I already have a function `isAuthenticated` that verifies the JWT and sets `res.locals.userId` to the UID retrieved; so I would like to simply make use of that in this new function `canModifyTarget` but for some reason the request hangs forever:

```
// This function works fine

isAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
  let token;
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then((decodedToken) => {
      res.locals.userId = decodedToken.uid;
      return next();
    }).catch((error) => {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).send();
    })
  }
}
```

---

```
// Switching out isAuthenticated for this in the route causes a permanent hang

canModifyTarget: function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('This is printed');
  return (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('This is NOT printed');
    isAuthenticated(req, res, () => {
      if (req.params.id === res.locals.userId) {
        return next();
      }
      return res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).send();
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

middlewares should be callback functions that call "next()" once finished.
Your first function, when executed, is calling next() (eventually, after your promise is resolved)

Your second function isn't calling next(), it is just returning a function definition.

Define it like this

```
canModifyTarget: function(req, res, next) {
    isAuthenticated(req, res, () => {
      if (req.params.id === res.locals.userId) {
        return next();
      }
      return res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).send();
    })
  }
}
```

and if the third parameter of isAuthenticated is a callback, it should work

Also, you should define an "else" case in your `isAuthenticated` function, otherwise it will hang as well (maybe throw an exception or something?)

If you need to reference them, store them in variables rather than directly defining them in your module.exports:

```
const isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
// code here
}

const canModifyTarget: function(req, res, next) {
// code here
 }

module.exports = {
   isAuthenticated,
   canModifyTarget,
};
```

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: isAuthenticated is not defined` even though they are both in the same `middleware.js` and inside `module.exports{}`

Comment: you should define them as functions with a variable, and then reference them from module.exports object. Otherwise there's no way to reference it

Answer (score 0):

I think simpler is to define `canModifyTarget` as one more middleware. I.e:

```
 function canModifyTarget(req, res, next) {
    console.log('This is NOT printed');
    if (req.params.id === res.locals.userId) {
     return next();
    }
    return res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).send();
  }
```

and then just apply it after `isAuthenticated` middleware:

```
app.put(
    '/users/:id',
    isAuthenticated,
    canModifyTarget,
   (req, res) => {db.updateUser(req.params.id, req.body)}
);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing a solution where I needed to unify two kind of auth middlewares: password-based and apikey-based into one middleware: unifiedOrgAuth middleware.

So, basically this would enable me to just put unifiedOrgAuth middleware on those routes which need either the password-based or apikey-based auth.

The key thing was to pass the `next` function from the umbrella middleware to the underlying middleware by just calling the underlying middleware with the `next` function of the umbrella middleware:

unified auth middleware:

```
function unifiedOrgAuthMiddleware(
  path: string,
  perm: Permission
): express.RequestHandler {
  return async (req: RequestWithOrg, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    if (cookies && cookies.Authorization) {
      (userAuthMiddleware(path, perm))(req, _res, next);
      return;
    }
    const apiKey = req.header('X-API-KEY');
    if (apiKey && apiKey.length > 0) {
      (apiAuthMiddleware(path, perm))(req, _res, next);
      return;
    }
    return next(new Error401Exception());
    // Make linter happy.
  };
}
```

Here are the underlying middlewares:

password-based auth middleware:

```
function userAuthMiddleware(
  path: string,
  perm: Permission
): express.RequestHandler {
  return async (req, _res, next) => {
    try {
      const cookies = req.cookies;
      if (!(cookies && cookies.Authorization)) {
        next(new Error401Exception());
        // Make linter happy.
        return;
      }
      if (!validCookies(cookies)) {
        next(new Error401Exception());
        // Make linter happy.
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      next(new Error401Exception());
      // Make linter happy.
      return;
    }
    next();
  };
}
```

api-based auth middleware:

```
function apiAuthMiddleware(
  path: string,
  perm: Permission
): express.RequestHandler {
  return async (req: RequestWithOrg, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const apiKey = req.header('X-API-KEY');
    if (!apiKey) {
      next(new Error401Exception());
      // Make linter happy.
      return;
    }
    if (!validApiKey(apiKey)) {
       next(new Error401Exception());
       // Make linter happy.
       return;
    }
    next();
  };
}
```