# How to use csurf within a custom middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I have managed to get `csurf` working in my `express` app as a regular middleware. However, I'd like to add it to my custom authentication middleware to both avoid having to include `csurf` in every route and also to avoid forgetting to use it. How should I call `csurf` within a custom middleware?

For example, say I have this middleware using `express-session` to limit access to logged-in users:

```
export const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { uid } = req.session;

  try {
    const user = await User.query().findById(uid);
    req.session.role = user.role;
    next();
  } catch {
    throw new PrivateRouteError();
  }
};
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34468490/7676920) has a way of doing this but I was unable to implement it. Here's what I tried:

```
export const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  const csrf = csurf({ cookie: true, ignoreMethods: [] });

  csrf(req, res, async () => {
    const { uid } = req.session;

    try {
      const user = await User.query().findById(uid);
      req.session.role = user.role;
      next();
    } catch {
      throw new PrivateRouteError();
    }
  });
};
```

However, the result is that `csurf` does not block access for a missing CSRF token and the `PrivateRouteError` is not caught and crashed the app (if the user has not authenticated, if they are it works fine).

Is there a neat way to bundle `csurf` into my middleware or should I just manually add it to all the routes that use the `auth` middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was clearly overthinking this last night. It's enough to get rid of the `next()` call and put `csurf` stuff after the catch block.

```
export const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { uid } = req.session;

  try {
    const user = await User.query().findById(uid);
    req.session.role = user.role;
  } catch {
    throw new PrivateRouteError();
  }

  const csrf = csurf({ cookie: true, ignoreMethods: [] });
  csrf(req, res, next);
};
```